# How to know menubar control item properties

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm just getting into ms-access.It's my first time on VB and ms-access, so forgive me if this is a basic question. I get an application of ms-access,it’s an .adp file . Need to custom this  application .
After double click on application show the bellow UI
[image]

Holding the Shift+Double click get the bellow UI
[image]

Holding the Alt+F11 get the bellow UI(Code)
[image]
picture-1 point out a **combo**. want to customize this combo.For this purpose need to know the combo name.

```
1)How to know the control name from my  ms-access .adp file.
2)By using smart navigation(like vs2010),In ms-Access combo is it possible to add combo items ?
3)How to get Smart Navigate items from combo
```

if have any query plz ask.any type of suggestion will be acceptable.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the name of the menu bar that is set. This menu bar is either set in the startup (application wide) or is set in the "other" tab of the startup form's property sheet. Also, while most controls can be added to custom menu bars via the built in UI (prior to Access 2007), a combo box is NOT one of those controls (so it takes code to add a combo box to a menu bar). This code could have been run "once" as a utility that added this control (it would likely persist to the application).

Another possibility is that code in the startup of the application adds the combo box to the custom menu bar.

Another possibility is that code in the startup of the application "creates" the menu bar and the combo box at startup with VBA code. In fact there is about maybe 15 different things to check here – an experienced Access developer can check these things out in about 10 minutes. However, to write out the 20 things to check and where to find these things and how to check these things would require some serious typing on my part and near a book.

So there is quite a learning curve to Access (a longer one then say using c# and writing code in VS2010).

Compounding this issue is that after Access 2003 the GUI parts that allow one to modify menu bars were removed. This means that you have to use Access 2003 or with 2007 onwards you have to use VBA code to create/maintain/update/modify a built in menu bar.

Furthermore since you ARE seeing a custom menu bar and NOT a ribbon but you ARE using a ribbon edition of Access then this means the database format you have is pre-2007 format (i.e.: was created in 2003 or before).

How bad you situation is will depend on if those menu bars are created in code, or previous by the GUI. I would say that "often" code is/was used in the startup to create or manage menu bars, but this may not be your case (you have to determine this by looking at the startup code that runs when the application starts).

However as noted even with Access 2003 adding a combo box to a menu bar ALWAYS required custom code. That custom code could have been onetime code writing and tossed out, or the code runs each time at startup. We don't know this answer unless we look at the code – as noted it is very possible that the code for the combo box was never kept (in other words, you can run code to create the combo box, and it will persist depending on how the code added the menu bar).

So first things is to check the system wide specified custom menu bar (or check if in fact there is one – they might not be).

As noted, compounding this issue is in 2007 you should see a ribbon NOT a menu bar. So this in itself is an issue you have to deal with (a bit of a trick is needed to make this happen in 2007). So how the menu bar was setup to display likely used this approach outlined here in this link:

http://www.accessribbon.de/en/index.php?FAQ

In the above, scroll down to

"I want my database created in A2003 or before to display my own menu bar only"

I can't direct link to above since it some type of AJAX page, so you have to scroll down and click on the link to expand it. The above link also shows where the options are in 2007 to set the system wide menu bar. You MUST determine this issue.

I would also consider doing a search for the keyword "commandbars" and see if any VBA code comes up. As noted the code to create that combo could have been run once and tossed out, or it might be part of the startup code. There is a higher probability that the code runs each time, but we don't know.

By the way, did you look at the startup code? The startup code is going to be in the form that is specified to run on startup in "most cases". However there ALSO could be a startup macro called "autoexec". So you also need to check the macro area if a macro called AutoExec exists (don't confuse the term macro and VBA code in Access – they are DIFFERENT concepts and different kinds of code).

As noted, holding down shift during startup disables BOTH autoexec macro and the startup form. This means you could have JUST an autoexc macro that does a bunch of things and THEN launches a startup form. Or perhaps you have just startup form. Or you can have both – all are possible and you have to check all cases here.

Access as a dev platform tends to have a rather long learning curve (I would say a good deal longer than learning say c# and VS2010).

If you going to have to do a lot of work on this project, you likely should bring someone in with a few years of experience, or the above 20 things to check will not take you 10 minutes to test, but each thing I ask might take you an hour to do the first time (so now you talking 20 or 30 hours of your time to check something that will take an experienced developer about 10 or 20 min tops).

A nice skill level check list is this:

(generally there are a "lot" of skill levels, but the following breakdown is sufficient for starting out for a project of this type).

```
Stage 1 Innocent (never heard of the product)

Stage 2 Aware (Has read an article about X)

Stage 3 Apprentice (has attended a three-day seminar)

Stage 4 Practitioner (ready to use X on a real project)

Stage 5 Journeyman (uses X naturally and automatically in his job)  

Stage 6 Master (has internalized X, knows when to break the rules)  

Stage 7 Expert (writes books, gives lectures, looks for ways to extend x)
```

One should NEVER attempt a project with a team consisting with Stage 3 or lower people. This is a sure fire formula for failure. The team can consist of stage 4's, but they should have at least access to Stage 5, or 6. (above ref:  Page-Jones, Meilir. "The Seven Stages of Expertise in Software Engineering", American Programmer, July-Aug 1990).

So depending on how much time you have to invest here, you might want to bring in someone with experience here – especially those who done menu bars and worked with ADP's.

Regardless, the above should get you started, but given your questions already you are much in over your head and are unable to do basic tasks in Access required for developing in Access.